# How can I get 'autodoc' work?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

When I `make html` the Sphinx documentation of [this little project](https://github.com/MartinThoma/lumix_map_tool) I get:

```
$ make html
sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
Running Sphinx v1.1.3
loading pickled environment... done
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index                                                                                                                      
/home/moose/Downloads/lumix_map_tool/doc/index.rst:16: WARNING: don't know which module to import for autodocumenting u'maptool' (try placing a "module" or "currentmodule" directive in the document, or giving an explicit module name)
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index                                                                                                                       
writing additional files... genindex search
copying static files... done
dumping search index... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 1 warning.
```

My dicrectory structure is

```
.
├── doc (automaticall generated by sphinx-quickstart)
├── LICENSE
├── maptool.log
├── maptool.py
└── README.md
```

and I have added `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/moose/Downloads/lumix_map_tool/'))` to `doc/conf.py`.

Why doesn't Sphinx find `maptool.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a module called `maptool`, but in index.rst in your GitHub project it says:

```
.. autoclass:: maptool
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
```

It should work if you change `autoclass`  to `automodule`.